# value is not assigning to a variable first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, global-variables, web-sql

alert(result_set) displays null for the first time, but when this funcition is called 2nd time, it shows proper value. There is a simple button that is executing this function. The global variable lesson_no is set first time properly, but result_set is not setting up first time.

Here goes my jquery mobile code:

```
result_set=null;
//load database for the lesson
 function loadLesson(lessonno){
     $(".audio-pause").hide();
     stopAudio();
     clearMarker(); 
     lesson_no = lessonno; 
     $("#lessonno").html("Lesson "+lesson_no);
     $("#lessonImage").attr("src","lessons/Lesson_"+lesson_no+".png");    
     $('.audio-position').html("");

    var sql =  "select Lesson,x1,y1,x2,y2,starttime from lessoninfo where Lesson="+lesson_no;
    db.transaction (function (transaction){
        transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, function (transaction, result){ //alert(result.rows.length);
            result_set = result;
        });
    });alert(result_set)
    setImageVariables();
    markerCount=0;
    $(".audio-play").show();
 }
```

Comment: I think `db.transaction` is asynchronous, it's normal that it doesn't update the variable until the callback is executed.

Comment: t does work properly when I call this function 2nd time using a mouse click, but not first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web SQL is asynchronous, like AJAX. Anything that depends on the result set must be done in the callback function.

```
 function loadLesson(lessonno){
     $(".audio-pause").hide();
     stopAudio();
     clearMarker(); 
     lesson_no = lessonno; 
     $("#lessonno").html("Lesson "+lesson_no);
     $("#lessonImage").attr("src","lessons/Lesson_"+lesson_no+".png");    
     $('.audio-position').html("");

    var sql =  "select Lesson,x1,y1,x2,y2,starttime from lessoninfo where Lesson="+lesson_no;
    db.transaction (function (transaction){
        transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined, function (transaction, result){ //alert(result.rows.length);
            result_set = result;
            alert(result_set);
            setImageVariables();
            markerCount=0;
            $(".audio-play").show();
        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: My funciton does work properly when I call this function 2nd time using a mouse click, but not first time

Comment: I think you need to study what "asynchronous" means. `db.transaction()` returns immediately, it doesn't wait for the query to be done or the callback function to run. The variable won't be set until that happens, which is later. That's why the variable isn't set.

Comment: What you're seeing is that when you click the 2nd time, you're seeing tha value that was set the 1st time.

Comment: I have put all statements within transaction.executeSql as you mentioned, and it works now :) Thanks for the help